# How to create table from views and display it to HTML?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How do I create a table using this query that corresponds to each other?

**views.py**

```
corevalues = CoreValues.objects.all().order_by('Display_Sequence')
marking = StudentBehaviorMarking.objects.all()
corevaluesdescription = CoreValuesDescription.objects.values('id', 'Description').distinct(
        'Description').order_by('Description')
period = gradingPeriod.objects.filter(id=coreperiod).order_by('Display_Sequence')
studentcorevalues = StudentsCoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher).filter(
            GradeLevel=gradelevel.values_list('Description')) \
            .values('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by(
            'Students_Enrollment_Records')
student = StudentPeriodSummary.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher).filter(
            GradeLevel__in=gradelevel.values_list('id'))
```

**The results I want to achieve**:

[image: results image]

**My models**

```
class CoreValues(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    .

class CoreValuesDescription(models.Model):
    Core_Values = models.ForeignKey(CoreValues,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class StudentBehaviorMarking(models.Model):
    Marking = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    Non_numerical_Rating = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

class StudentPeriodSummary(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentSubjectGrade,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It is possible to create a table using Python, right?

**UPDATE**

When I try this to my **views.py**:

```
students = StudentsCoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(grading_Period=coreperiod) \
            .values('id', 'Marking',
                    'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname',
                    'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname') \
            .distinct(
            'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname',
            'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname') \
            .order_by(
            'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname',
            'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname')

        gradelevel = EducationLevel.objects.filter(id__in=coregradelevel).distinct().order_by('id')
        markings = StudentBehaviorMarking.objects.all()
        corevaluesperiod = CoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(grading_Period=coreperiod).order_by('Display_Sequence')
        table = []
        student_name = None
        table_row = None
        columns = len(corevaluesperiod) + 1

        table_header = ['Core Values']
        table_header.extend(corevaluesperiod)


        table.append(table_header)
        for student in students:
            if not student[
                       'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname'] + ' ' + \
                   student[
                       'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname'] == student_name:
                if not table_row is None:
                    table.append(table_row)
                table_row = [None for d in range(columns)]
                student_name = student[
                                   'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname'] + ' ' + \
                               student[
                                   'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname']
                table_row[0] = student_name
                print(table_row[0])
            table_row[student.index(gradelevel['Description']) + 1] = markings['Marking']
        table.append(table_row)
        return render(request, "Homepage/behavior.html", {"table": table, "corevaluesperiod" \
            : corevaluesperiod, "corevalues": corevalues, "marking": marking})
```

This is how I post data to my **html**:

```
 <tr>
        {% for v in table.0 %}
        <th id="thupdate">{{ v }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        <th  hidden></th>
    </tr>

    <tbody>
    {% for row in table|slice:"1:" %}
        <tr class="tr2update">
            <td>{{ row.0  }}</td>
             <td class="tdupdate" hidden><input type="text" hidden></td>
            {% for c in row|slice:"1:" %}
            <td><input type="text" id="oldgrade" class="oldgrade" name="gradeupdate" value="{{c}}"></td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
```

This is the **result** in my web page:

[image: Result as image file]

Comment: have you looked at the django tables module?: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/# .

Comment: can i control the header and column there? although many models are used?

Comment: doubt django-tables has the level of fine control for the cell-spans implied in the 1st row and top-left cell.

Comment: so this is the answer? or I have to create table through views?

Comment: Hi. It seems part of what you need to do is CSS. e.g. your `td`s need borders. Maybe as a start try updating the `tdupdate` class to include `border: 1px solid gray`. Also, you have `<th id="thupdate">` in the loop for the header, but I believe you want `class="thupdate"` instead. `id`s are meant to be unique on the page.

Comment: that header is is printed because of my logic in views,

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, **begging and pleading**, **how long you've been stuck**, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer noted..

Comment: It looks like you've been making a lot of redundant edits in order to bump the post to the front page. This is not particularly ethical behaviour - volunteers will look at your question at their leisure. Please refrain from doing this. The best way to get your question seen is to make it specific, succinct and answerable.

Comment: @halfer I thought its okay doing that, don't worry I'll never do that again,